# Adobe Premiere Background Processes

Tags: premiere, adobe

Premiere keeps running in the background, eating up a lot of RAM, but I can't figure out why. I have to keep manually stopping it.

[image: Premiere Background Processes]

In addition to this, the program keeps refusing to have video playback. It will do audio of the videos but not the videos themselves. I've tried everything that I can find on the internet and NOTHING works.

Have any of you experienced this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a large allocation of memory for Premiere. It's only holding as private memory just under 4GB.

My recommendation would be to add additional memory to you system.

I personally would recommend a minimum of 32 GB, but if your overhead is low in general, you can get away with less and not have any issues.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. It's not the RAM usage that bothers me during use. This happens when I'm NOT using the software. It's closed.

Answer (score 0):

A reinstall with the CC Cleaner could do the trick: https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/cc-cleaner-tool-installation-problems.html